# QProcess Mac OS , Cant launch executable with arguments

Tags: macos, qprocess, osx-yosemite

/usr/local/bin/rdesktop  launched from terminal connects me to host

following launches rdesktop without arguments:

```
 QString program = "/usr/local/bin/rdesktop";
    QStringList args;
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    args << m_address;
    process->start("open \""+program);
    process->setArguments(args);
```

have tried with same result:

```
process->startDetached("open \""+program);
process->execute("open \""+program);
```

also with arguments overloaded func process.start("open \""+program, args)
and it doesnt launch anything and no error message either.

some advice please?

Comment: `open` only works with apps, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi Droppy , open - opens the app i am trying to open, problem i am facing is with the arguments. program works well in linux and windows, but first time i am trying it on mac and well im ...stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
process->start("open \""+program);
process->setArguments(args);
```

As you're setting the arguments after you call QProcess::start, the process will not receive the arguments when launching your desired program.

As the documentation for [QProcess::setArguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setArguments) states

> Set the arguments to pass to the called program when starting the process. **This function must be called before start().**

Comment: Hi TheDarkKnight, thanks for the tip. The following worked (documentation link):                                                                                                            process->setProgram(program);
        process->setArguments(args);
        process->start();

Answer (score 0):

Worked...

QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);

QString program = "/usr/local/bin/rdesktop";

QStringList args;

args << m_address;

process->setProgram(program);

process->setArguments(args);

process->start();